# 2 floated DIVs and 1 centered DIV in a parent DIV

Tags: css, html

I have a parent DIV with 3 children DIVs. I need to float left one DIV, float right another DIV, and center the 3rd DIV.

The parent width is 100% so not fixed.

I tried the following but the DIV is not centered:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<div style="width:100%;border:1px solid #000000;height:200px;">

<div style="width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid #000000;margin-top:75px;margin-
left:20px;float:left"></div>

<div style="width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid #000000;margin-top:75px;margin-
left:auto;margin-right:auto;float:left;"></div>

<div style="width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid #000000;margin-top:75px;margin-
right:20px;float:right;"></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I created a fiddle for you to test: http://jsfiddle.net/swS5x/

Thanks

Comment: just remove float:left from center div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swS5x/

Comment: this will push the right floated DIV down

Comment: Sorry, pushed back so last edit didnt save http://jsfiddle.net/swS5x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one of the solutions could be to simply add for the #parent add `text-align:center;` and on #center, remove the `float:left;` and add `display:inline-block;`

```
#parent {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
#center {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    margin-top:75px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The display:inline-block; makes the element behave much like an image would, which you can center inside a container.

http://jsfiddle.net/swS5x/2/

Comment: this is exactly what i needed in my case...thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can, reorder your `div` elements and don't `float` the `#center`

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/swS5x/1/)

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

A floated element will ignore `margin: auto` for the left and right margins.

Comment: kudos for the very simple approach i haven't thought of!